# Extracting number of digits of terminating decimal

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

Let $x \in [0, 1)$ have a terminating decimal expansion. This means that $x$ almost certainly is not an integer and that a decimal expansion of $x$ eventually has an infinite string of only "0"s in it. Note that there are other decimal expansions of $x$ which do not terminate (but they should be nontrivially/non-"0"-ly repetitious); ignore these. Call the shortest terminating decimal expansion of $x$ "the canonical expansion of $x$".

This does require that $x \in \mathbb{Q}:$ the most-reduced denominator of $x$ is coprime to all primes other than, at most, some of the prime factors of the base (here: $10$).

How can one extract the number of digits in  canonical expansion of $x$ (ignoring the infinite tail string of "0"s)?

For example, if we wanted the number of like digits in an integer $n$, then we could just calculate $\operatorname{floor}{(\log_{10}{(n)})} + 1$. I would like the same thing, but for integers divided by some power of the base.

Alternatively, extraction of the result of the power of the base which could form the denominator (not necessarily in most-reduced form) would work too, given that we know how to get that power via logarithm.

Ideally, the following constraints would be met:
(1) Nothing like "just count them".
(2) Nothing iterative.
(3) No limits or infinite sequences, except implicitly in the definitions of common functions such as $\log$.

This should work for any base, although we are using decimal here.

Comment: In order for $x$ to have a terminating decimal, it must be the case that $10^nx$ is an integer for some $n$. The answer you want is the least such $n$.

Comment: I would suggest looking at writing $x= \frac{a}{2^b 5^c}$ where $a,b,c$ are nonnegative integers and $a$ is coprime to $10$, and then consider the larger of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: It depends, of course, on how you are given the number $x$.  It's hard to use logs, or similar analytic means, since, say, $.1$ is hard to distinguish from $.0999999999$

Comment: @lulu: But how to identify that $n$ without iterating/counting?

Comment: What's wrong with counting?  As I said, you aren't going to find a sensible analytic method (since "short" decimals are arbitrarily close to "long" decimals).  If you are given $x$ as a quotient of coprime integers you can just look at the orders to which $2,5$ divide the denominator.

Comment: But, really, your question is not clear.  If you are just given $x$ as a string of digits, then you'll need to know which is the "final" digit.  Is that handed to you? If it is, just look at the location of the final digit.   If all you have is a program which is returning digits, just seeing a long string of $0's$ doesn't prove that the string has terminated.

Comment: I know that the string terminates. I do not know where. And I would want something analytical because I would be calculating this by hand.

Comment: But, yes, your point about arbitrary-closeness is pretty convincing...